# "virtual ethernet failed" for VMWare station 17.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, kernel, vmware

I installed VMWare Workstation pro 17.0.0 (build-20800274) on Ubuntu 22.04 (`5.19.0-38-generic`). However, I can't access the internet from the guest machine. I searched the internet and tried some resolutions (e.g. https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Virtual-ethernet-failed/td-p/2906720). But they don't seem to work. For example, I tried to install some patch and compile modules.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules
git checkout workstation-17.0.0
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then I compile the modules.

```bash
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

However, I got the following messages.

```
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/moduleloop.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/sharedAreaVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/statVarsVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/bootstrap/vmmblob.o
/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: 'naked' return found in RETHUNK build
/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o: warning: objtool: CrossPage_CodePage+0x207: missing int3 after ret
/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Free() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Add()
/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Add() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Remove()
/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o: warning: objtool: PhysTrack_Remove() falls through to next function PhysTrack_Test()
/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
  BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-38-generic/build/include/.. M=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/userif.o: warning: objtool: VNetCsumCopyDatagram+0x5e: call to csum_partial_copy_nocheck() with UACCESS enabled
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  MODPOST /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/Module.symvers
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
  BTF [M] /tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-38-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-KNOgx7/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
Unable to start services
```

I reinstall the VMware workstation pro and the modules several times. But I cannot make it work.

---

My Ubuntu host can access the Internet. I tried the command `sudo service vmware-networks restart` and got the following error.

```
Failed to restart vmware-networks.service: Unit vmware-networks.service not found.
```

I also run the command `ifconfig -a`. There are no something like `vmnet1` and `vmnet8`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and it was really bothering me.
I deleted the `vmnet8` from virtual network (comes with vmware workstation package) and remake it with same specs.
At the end, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**#problem statement**
I think it is about the new version of vmware 17 or 17.5
vmware workstation does not loaded vmnet that affects virtual interface connections.

**#solution ( worked for me)**
Follow this link but I have summarised it below. Follow these steps.
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Virtual-ethernet-failed/td-p/2906720

##download, extract and go inside of the file.

```
wget https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/archive/workstation-17.0.0.tar.gz

tar -xzf workstation-17.0.0.tar.gz
```

**##tar these files coming from the wget file that will be replaced original vmware files later**

```
  tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
  tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
```

**#copy them into the original vmware folder**

```
 sudo cp -v vmmon.tar vmnet.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/
```

##run this command to build or compile vmware files or services.

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

##if it gives error, disable vmware services.

```
sudo systemctl disable vmware-USBArbitrator.service
sudo systemctl disable vmware.service
```

##reboot your computer and run the same command without any error

sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

enable the same services them again and test vmnet configurations

**#debug command, use it to see exact error.**

```
sudo dmesg | grep vmnet
```